# vb6 unattended execution is grayed out

Tags: vb6, activex

I am looking at an old VB6 ActiveX .dll that has the unattended execution and retained in memory check boxed grayed out.  I found out that happens when a form is attached to the project.  I removed the form, yet the boxes remain grayed out.

What do I have to do to make them click-able?

Comment: You don't have the debugger running, do you? Did you change the project type to allow adding the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried this with a brand new VB6 ActiveX dll project and you're right that the unattended exectution box is grayed-out after a form is added, but the box is enabled again as soon as the form is removed.

The project was as simple as you can get - a single class and a single form, so I don't know if there are any other elements in your project that will keep the check box grayed out.

**Update:**
I've just tried this the other way round.  I enabled unattended execution to see what I then **cannot** add to the project.  This includes:

- Form
- User Control
- Property Page
- User Document
- Data Report
- Components (Ctrl-T)

Answer (score 0):

I actually just found the answer here:

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=125144&page=1997

I went through the components of the project and found that there was one.  Once I unchecked the component and then commented out all the code that the application was referencing for that component, then the checkbox became clickable.

Now I have to figure out if we can remove that component out of this particular .dll